# Religion specific units in Fall from Heaven 2?

Tags: mods, civilization-4, fall-from-heaven-2

In Fall from Heaven 2, there are religion specific units such as the "Fawn".  To build these units do you need the religion in the city you're building them, or that religion as your state religion, or both?

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a clear cut answer to this, since the answer is `sometimes`.

For example,

### Ashenveil

#### As City Religion, you can build

- Savant
- Temple of the Veil

#### As State Religion, you can build

- Beast of Agares
- Demons' Altar
- Diseased Corpses
- Infernal Pact
- Profane
- Ritualist
- Sacrifice the Weak

However, Ritualists and Beasts require a Temple of the Veil.  Now a Temple of the Veil doesn't require the City religion be Ashenveil to use, but it does require to be built.

The rule of thumb is:

- Units which spread religion require that religion on the city where they're built
- Building a temple requires the city have that religion
- Some units  that require the Temple, don't require the City religion (unless they spread)
- Other units require the State Religion

Comment: Is there a way to tell the difference from the Civlopedia entry? Unless I'm mistaken, they both show the same icon there.

Comment: @Cross I don't believe so. However, its usually very easy to identify the ones that spread religion as they have the following properties: 
Starts With:
Cannot Pillage,
Medic I,
Can spread X,
Can sacrifice for 15 Science.  Outside of them you can see which ones require temple pretty easily.